# I get ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH on apache server (installed with xampp on windows)

Tags: apache-http-server

I have this version of Apache installed:

###### ApacheFriends XAMPP (Basispaket) version 1.6.8

- Apache 2.2.9
- MySQL 5.0.67 (Community Server)
- PHP 5.2.6 + PHP 4.4.9 + PEAR
- OpenSSL 0.9.8i

The ssl certificate was enabled, but I get this error on browser if I try to access https://localhost :

```
localhost uses an unsupported protocol.
ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
Unsupported protocol
The client and server don't support a common SSL protocol version or cipher suite.
```

Apache erorr log:

```
[Fri Apr 07 13:58:23 2023] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) **name_of_the site** does NOT match server name!?
[Fri Apr 07 13:58:24 2023] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) **name_of_the site** does NOT match server name!?
[Fri Apr 07 13:58:24 2023] [notice] Child 9956: Child process is running
[Fri Apr 07 13:58:24 2023] [notice] Child 9956: Acquired the start mutex.
[Fri Apr 07 13:58:24 2023] [notice] Child 9956: Starting 250 worker threads.
[Fri Apr 07 13:58:24 2023] [notice] Child 9956: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Fri Apr 07 13:58:24 2023] [notice] Child 9956: Starting thread to listen on port 443.
```

This is the httpd-ssl.conf file:

```
#
# This is the Apache server configuration file providing SSL support.
# It contains the configuration directives to instruct the server how to
# serve pages over an https connection. For detailing information about these
# directives see <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html>
#
# Do NOT simply read the instructions in here without understanding
# what they do.  They're here only as hints or reminders.  If you are unsure
# consult the online docs. You have been warned.
#

#
# Pseudo Random Number Generator (PRNG):
# Configure one or more sources to seed the PRNG of the SSL library.
# The seed data should be of good random quality.
# WARNING! On some platforms /dev/random blocks if not enough entropy
# is available. This means you then cannot use the /dev/random device
# because it would lead to very long connection times (as long as
# it requires to make more entropy available). But usually those
# platforms additionally provide a /dev/urandom device which doesn't
# block. So, if available, use this one instead. Read the mod_ssl User
# Manual for more details.
#
#SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/random  512
#SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom 512
#SSLRandomSeed connect file:/dev/random  512
#SSLRandomSeed connect file:/dev/urandom 512


#
# When we also provide SSL we have to listen to the
# standard HTTP port (see above) and to the HTTPS port
#
# Note: Configurations that use IPv6 but not IPv4-mapped addresses need two
#       Listen directives: "Listen [::]:443" and "Listen 0.0.0.0:443"
#
Listen 443

##
##  SSL Global Context
##
##  All SSL configuration in this context applies both to
##  the main server and all SSL-enabled virtual hosts.
##

#
#   Some MIME-types for downloading Certificates and CRLs
#
AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt
AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl    .crl

#   Pass Phrase Dialog:
#   Configure the pass phrase gathering process.
#   The filtering dialog program (`builtin' is a internal
#   terminal dialog) has to provide the pass phrase on stdout.
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin

#   Inter-Process Session Cache:
#   Configure the SSL Session Cache: First the mechanism
#   to use and second the expiring timeout (in seconds).
#SSLSessionCache        shmcb:logs/ssl_scache(512000)
SSLSessionCache         dbm:logs/ssl.scache
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

#   Semaphore:
#   Configure the path to the mutual exclusion semaphore the
#   SSL engine uses internally for inter-process synchronization.
SSLMutex  default

##
## SSL Virtual Host Context
##

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    #   General setup for the virtual host
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/name_of_the_site"

    ServerName localhost:443
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost

    ErrorLog logs/error.log
    <IfModule log_config_module>
        CustomLog logs/access.log combined
    </IfModule>

    #   SSL Engine Switch:
    #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
    SSLEngine on

    #   SSL Cipher Suite:
    #   List the ciphers that the client is permitted to negotiate.
    #   See the mod_ssl documentation for a complete list.
  
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
        #   Server Certificate:
    #   Point SSLCertificateFile at a PEM encoded certificate.  If
    #   the certificate is encrypted, then you will be prompted for a
    #   pass phrase.  Note that a kill -HUP will prompt again.  Keep
    #   in mind that if you have both an RSA and a DSA certificate you
    #   can configure both in parallel (to also allow the use of DSA
    #   ciphers, etc.)
    #SSLCertificateFile conf/ssl.crt/snakeoil-rsa.crt
    #SSLCertificateFile conf/ssl.crt/snakeoil-dsa.crt
    # @SSLCertificateFile conf/ssl.crt/server.crt
#Radu
SSLCertificateFile conf/ssl.crt/name_of_the_site.crt
    #   Server Private Key:
    #   If the key is not combined with the certificate, use this
    #   directive to point at the key file.  Keep in mind that if
    #   you've both a RSA and a DSA private key you can configure
    #   both in parallel (to also allow the use of DSA ciphers, etc.)
    #SSLCertificateKeyFile conf/ssl.key/snakeoil-rsa.key
    #SSLCertificateKeyFile conf/ssl.key/snakeoil-dsa.key
    # @SSLCertificateKeyFile conf/ssl.key/server.key
#Radu
SSLCertificateKeyFile conf/ssl/name_of_the_site.key

    #   Server Certificate Chain:
    #   Point SSLCertificateChainFile at a file containing the
    #   concatenation of PEM encoded CA certificates which form the
    #   certificate chain for the server certificate. Alternatively
    #   the referenced file can be the same as SSLCertificateFile
    #   when the CA certificates are directly appended to the server
    #   certificate for convinience.
    #SSLCertificateChainFile conf/ssl.crt/ca.crt
# Radu
SSLCertificateChainFile conf/ssl/name_of_the_site-chain.pem

    #   Certificate Authority (CA):
    #   Set the CA certificate verification path where to find CA
    #   certificates for client authentication or alternatively one
    #   huge file containing all of them (file must be PEM encoded)
    #   Note: Inside SSLCACertificatePath you need hash symlinks
    #         to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
    #         Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
    #SSLCACertificatePath conf/ssl.crt
    #SSLCACertificateFile conf/ssl.crt/ca-bundle.crt

    #   Certificate Revocation Lists (CRL):
    #   Set the CA revocation path where to find CA CRLs for client
    #   authentication or alternatively one huge file containing all
    #   of them (file must be PEM encoded)
    #   Note: Inside SSLCARevocationPath you need hash symlinks
    #         to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
    #         Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
    #SSLCARevocationPath conf/ssl.crl
    #SSLCARevocationFile conf/ssl.crl/ca-bundle.crl

    #   Client Authentication (Type):
    #   Client certificate verification type and depth.  Types are
    #   none, optional, require and optional_no_ca.  Depth is a
    #   number which specifies how deeply to verify the certificate
    #   issuer chain before deciding the certificate is not valid.
    #SSLVerifyClient require
    #SSLVerifyDepth  10

    #   Access Control:
    #   With SSLRequire you can do per-directory access control based
    #   on arbitrary complex boolean expressions containing server
    #   variable checks and other lookup directives.  The syntax is a
    #   mixture between C and Perl.  See the mod_ssl documentation
    #   for more details.
    <Location />
        #SSLRequire (    %{SSL_CIPHER} !~ m/^(EXP|NULL)/ \
        #            and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_O} eq "Snake Oil, Ltd." \
        #            and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_OU} in {"Staff", "CA", "Dev"} \
        #            and %{TIME_WDAY} >= 1 and %{TIME_WDAY} <= 5 \
        #            and %{TIME_HOUR} >= 8 and %{TIME_HOUR} <= 20       ) \
        #           or %{REMOTE_ADDR} =~ m/^192\.76\.162\.[0-9]+$/
    </Location>

    #   SSL Engine Options:
    #   Set various options for the SSL engine.
    #   o FakeBasicAuth:
    #     Translate the client X.509 into a Basic Authorisation.  This means that
    #     the standard Auth/DBMAuth methods can be used for access control.  The
    #     user name is the `one line' version of the client's X.509 certificate.
    #     Note that no password is obtained from the user. Every entry in the user
    #     file needs this password: `xxj31ZMTZzkVA'.
    #   o ExportCertData:
    #     This exports two additional environment variables: SSL_CLIENT_CERT and
    #     SSL_SERVER_CERT. These contain the PEM-encoded certificates of the
    #     server (always existing) and the client (only existing when client
    #     authentication is used). This can be used to import the certificates
    #     into CGI scripts.
    #   o StdEnvVars:
    #     This exports the standard SSL/TLS related `SSL_*' environment variables.
    #     Per default this exportation is switched off for performance reasons,
    #     because the extraction step is an expensive operation and is usually
    #     useless for serving static content. So one usually enables the
    #     exportation for CGI and SSI requests only.
    #   o StrictRequire:
    #     This denies access when "SSLRequireSSL" or "SSLRequire" applied even
    #     under a "Satisfy any" situation, i.e. when it applies access is denied
    #     and no other module can change it.
    #   o OptRenegotiate:
    #     This enables optimized SSL connection renegotiation handling when SSL
    #     directives are used in per-directory context.
    #SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php|php5|php4|php3)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory "C:/xampp/apache/cgi-bin">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    #   SSL Protocol Adjustments:
    #   The safe and default but still SSL/TLS standard compliant shutdown
    #   approach is that mod_ssl sends the close notify alert but doesn't wait for
    #   the close notify alert from client. When you need a different shutdown
    #   approach you can use one of the following variables:
    #   o ssl-unclean-shutdown:
    #     This forces an unclean shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. no
    #     SSL close notify alert is send or allowed to received.  This violates
    #     the SSL/TLS standard but is needed for some brain-dead browsers. Use
    #     this when you receive I/O errors because of the standard approach where
    #     mod_ssl sends the close notify alert.
    #   o ssl-accurate-shutdown:
    #     This forces an accurate shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. a
    #     SSL close notify alert is send and mod_ssl waits for the close notify
    #     alert of the client. This is 100% SSL/TLS standard compliant, but in
    #     practice often causes hanging connections with brain-dead browsers. Use
    #     this only for browsers where you know that their SSL implementation
    #     works correctly.
    #   Notice: Most problems of broken clients are also related to the HTTP
    #   keep-alive facility, so you usually additionally want to disable
    #   keep-alive for those clients, too. Use variable "nokeepalive" for this.
    #   Similarly, one has to force some clients to use HTTP/1.0 to workaround
    #   their broken HTTP/1.1 implementation. Use variables "downgrade-1.0" and
    #   "force-response-1.0" for this.
    <IfModule setenvif_module>
        BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" \
                 nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                 downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    </IfModule>

    #   Per-Server Logging:
    #   The home of a custom SSL log file. Use this when you want a
    #   compact non-error SSL logfile on a virtual host basis.
    <IfModule log_config_module>
        CustomLog logs/ssl_request.log \
                  "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: The question if off-topic on Security SE. Nevertheless, check what the error message says: Check if the server name in the Apache config matches the name in the certificate.

Comment: Your certificate does not use the name "localhost"

Comment: I have changed it to the server name, but I still get same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you're using OpenSSL 0.9.8, which only supports TLS 1.0.  However, TLS 1.0 is no longer considered secure, and [RFC 8996 section 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8996.html) says this:

> TLS 1.0 MUST NOT be used. Negotiation of TLS 1.0 from any version of TLS MUST NOT be permitted.

Section 5 prohibits its successor, TLS 1.1, in much the same way.

Your browser, assuming it is reasonably modern, will only support TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.3 (because TLS 1.0 and 1.1 are insecure and forbidden), but your version of OpenSSL cannot support those versions.  Pretty much nobody with a secure system is going to be able to connect to that site these days.

OpenSSL 0.9.8 also has no security updates and would be subject to numerous vulnerabilities if you could actually connect to it.  The same is true of your PHP versions.

The best thing to do is to upgrade to a supported distribution of your OS (or, if you've got this toolchain from ApacheFriends, to a supported version of that distribution).  That will ship software with security updates and a version of OpenSSL that will be able to function on the modern Internet.